# Function Overloading

Tags: c#, .net

Let us suppose i have these three methods defined:

```
int F1(int, int);
int F1(float, float);
Float F1(int, int);
```

and i am calling method F1 here:

```
Console.writeline(F1(5,6).ToString()));
```

Which method it will call and why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first and third function will not compile in the same namespace.

This is because function signatures are differentiated by type and number of parameters, and these are the same. Return types are not considered as part of the method signature.

If you only had the first and second (or second and third) in the name space, the most appropriate one would be called (the one with integer types passed in, as you are passing in integers).

Eric Lippert has some great [blog entries](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/default.aspx) about the subtleties of C#.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Add(3, 4,3);
    }
    public static void Add(int FN, int SN)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Total is {0}", FN + SN);
    }
    public static void Add(int FN, int SN, int TN)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Total is {0}", FN + SN + TN); 
    }
}
```

Method overloading and Function overloading terms are used interchangeably. Method overloading allows a class to have multiple methods with the same name. But with different signature. C# functions can be overloaded based on the number, type(int, float etc) and kind(Value, ref or out) of parameters.
          Signature of the method does not include return type and params modifier. So, It is not possible to overload a function based on return type and params modifier.

Comment: Name of a method is a part of the method signature, so this definition that "Method overloading allows a class to have multiple methods with the same name. But with different signature" is not quite correct! Perhaps it's better we say: Method overloading is implementing two or more methods with the same name but different in number, type, order and kind(ref/out/value) of parameters in a class

Answer (score 1):

compilation error because same function signature is used twice in your program!

```
int F1(int, int); 

Float F1(int, int);
```

function signature is **(name of function + number of arguments + type for each argument)** which is same in your case...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it?

You would think it should execute either:

```
int F1(int, int);
```

or

```
Float F1(int, int);
```

Function overloading, however, doesn't work on return values - it's the parameter types that have to be unique, so this wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

In C# it is *parameter* overloading, not function overloading.  You can change the input parameters for a method, which may lead to a different return type, but you cannot specify a differnt return type to distinguish your method.

Answer (score 0):

In Function overloading name of a functions are same but they are differ in either type of parameter or number of parameter.

In Function overloading return type of a function is not considered.

So this code will not even compile.Because you can not write exactly same function in one namespace.