# How to pass any class object as a parameter to method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 3 classes :-

```
public Class Example1
{
  public void Method1()
  {
  }
  public void Method2()
  {
  }
}

public Class Example2
{
  public void Method3()
  {
  }
  public void Method4()
  {
  }
}

public Class CompletelyDifferentClass
{
  public void DifferentMethod(Example1/Example2 obj)
  {
      obj.Method1(); //if object is passed for Example1
      obj.Method3(); //if object is passed for Example2
  }
}
```

If we see CompletelyDifferentClass and  public DifferentMethod(Example1/Example2 obj)

I want DifferentMethod to get parameter as any time I can send Example1 object or Example2 object.
If Example2 object is sent , it should enable methods for Example2 like obj.Method3();

It is not fixed that which class's object I am going to send as a parameter to that method.

How can I write a code for `DifferentMethod`

Comment: If you don't know the type of the object passed as an argument at compile time (typed `object`) then you need to read about [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx).

Comment: Use the `is` operator or the `as` operator, perhaps? But it sounds like overloads would be better. This sounds like a bit of an X-Y problem, and it's not clear what it has to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: [And many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=method+parameter+different+types+c%23)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a base class and then inherit your child classes from that base class.

Then you can pass any type of child class inheriting from the same class. Like

```
public class myBase{

}

public class A: myBase{

}

public class B: myBase{

}

public static void myFunction(myBase obj){

}
```

And you can pass any child class to ur base class like

```
myFunction(A);
myFunction(B);
```

Another way is to use method overloading. You can write same functions with same signature. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651413/function-overloading) is a good read for function overloading

Also you can take in object as a parameter type. Even better, perhaps, would be to use generics:

```
void MyFunction<T>(T parm) {

}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: How do you call different methods doing it like this?