# Type safety for passing in Types

Tags: c#

Currently I am in the phase of refactoring my code after it has been unit tested, and I have some concerns about the refactoring from a design point of view with regards to type safety. My original code looked a bit like this:

**Interfaces**

```
public interface IBase
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

public interface IFirstSub : IBase
{
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public interface ISecondSub : IBase
{
    decimal Total { get; set; }
}

public interface IThirdSub : IBase
{
    int Count { get; set; }
}

public interface IBaseContainer
{
    void Add(IBase baseParam);
}
```

**Implementations**

```
public class FirstContainer : IBaseContainer
{
    public void Add(IBase baseParam)
    {
        if (!(baseParam is IFirstSub || baseParam is ISecondSub))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(baseParam));
        }

        // Do Something
    }
}

public class SecondContainer : IBaseContainer
{
    public void Add(IBase baseParam)
    {
        if (!(baseParam is IThirdSub))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(baseParam));
        }

        // Do Something
    }
}
```

With my original implementation of `FirstContainer` and `SecondContainer`, it was repeating the same logic at the start of the `Add` method, so I thought I would refactor the code to look something *like* this:

```
public abstract class BaseContainer : IBaseContainer
{
    private readonly List<Type> _types = new List<Type>();

    protected BaseContainer(params Type[] baseTypes)
    {
        _types.AddRange(baseTypes);
    }

    public void Add(IBase baseParam)
    {
        if (_types.All(type => !type.IsInstanceOfType(baseParam)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(baseParam));
        }

        DoSomething(baseParam);
    }

    protected abstract void DoSomething(IBase baseParam);
}

public class ThirdContainer : BaseContainer
{
    public ThirdContainer() : base(typeof(IFirstSub)) { }

    protected override void DoSomething(IBase baseParam)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

With this refactoring done, it successfully removes the duplication of the code from the start of the `Add` method, but my main concern with the refactoring is the fact that the call to the base constructor `base(typeof(IFirstSub))` is not really type safe. By that, I mean I can call the base constructor like `base(typeof(object))` for example, and it will compile. For the purposes of my project, I'd like to constrain the types to ones that inherit `IBase`, and enforce at compile time.

Is there anyway to overcome this limitation, or would a new design be needed in order to achieve this?

Comment: Generics and `where T : IBase`?

Comment: Are you trying to do this without using generics? `public abstract class BaseContainer<T> : IBaseContainer where T : IBase` would work.

Comment: Generics won't work for my solution as it requires that only certain `IBase` implementations gets accepted. e.g. `FirstContainer` can use `IFirstSub` and `ISecondSub` but `SecondContainer` uses `IThirdSub`.

Comment: Unless I am missing how generics interact with types.

Comment: Can make a ```List<IBase>``` instead?

Comment: "Generics won't work for my solution as it requires that only certain IBase implementations gets accepted" I suggest you ponder very carefully why only certain implementations get accepted, and associate that with a concept. What would that concept be called? I suspect there is something missing from your object model.

Comment: I am uncertain if you should use abstract classes like that. While they have some properties (you can provide some code and define fields), what I usually consider the most important is their place in the inheritance chain. For me they are for "primary, exclusive" purposes. Interfaces are for "secondary" and "primary, non-exclsuive" purposes. But this is a mater of personal preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No it's not type safe

Passing and validating types at run-time is not type-safe, as type-safety is a compile-time concept. In my opinion your refactoring effort does not improve the code, and in fact does something quite weird.

### Function overloading

If you need a method that accepts either of two types, you can use [function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651413/function-overloading):

```
public class FirstContainer : IBaseContainer
{
    public void Add(IFirstSub param)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    public void Add(ISecondSub param)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

The compiler will automatically choose the right prototype for you, and will not allow anything other than an `IFirstSub` or `ISecondSub`.

### Create another interface

Another approach requires you to add an interface for the types that have something in common, like this:

```
interface ICanBeHeldInFirstContainer
{ }

public interface IFirstSub : IBase, ICanBeHeldInFirstContainer
{
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public interface ISecondSub : IBase, ICanBeHeldInFirstContainer
{
    decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Then you do this:

```
public class FirstContainer : IBaseContainer
{
    public void Add(ICanBeHeldInFirstContainer param)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

or this:

```
public class FirstContainer : IBaseContainer
{
    public void Add<T>(T param) where T : ICanBeHeldInFirstContainer 
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first method would work in theory, if I wasn't going to be calling my methods from an interface. As it is, the first example doesn't compile unless you add `Add(IBase)` back in, and I'd be calling `Add` through an interface (i.e. `IBaseContainer container = new FirstContainer(); container.Add(/*blah*/);`) which calls `Add(IBase)`.

The second option won't be feasible, as there will be a lot of `IBase` subtypes which has a many-to-many relationships with containers. It would work, but is not ideal by any means.

Comment: Also, are you able comment on what you mean by the refactoring does something weird. Just want to know for educational purposes.

Comment: "First method would work, if I wasn't going to be calling from an interface." If a programmer believes your interface, he'll think `Add()` accepts any kind of `IBase`. Isn't that a concern?

Comment: "The second option won't be feasible, as there will be a lot of IBase subtypes which have m:m relationships with containers." You don't need to call it `ICanBeHeldInXXX`, you just need to figure out why those interfaces are treated like they're special, and give that a name, which could work in any or all of your containers if you choose. For example, `IHasDescription` means that any container that needs a description can accept the object. You can then use that to constrain the input parameter in a type-safe way.

Comment: Yeah it would be a concern, but I am unfamiliar with another approach to the problem. Am I able to describe the problem further to you in a chatroom here on stackoverflow?

Comment: In either case, I'll need to rethink my design of how I am associating different `IBase` to each other as you've mentioned. I'll approve this.

Comment: I can join a chat briefly, but I suggest you modify your question to include any other important details. I think the rationale for for allowing two interfaces that are not logically grouped will be germane to the answer.